# call a function each time page changed in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatables

I am using jquery and datatables but stuck in somewhere.I have a gridview and I am trying make something like alerting the id of the selected row. My onclick event only works for first page's datas and thats understandable since I only call it when table first populated. So how can I make that function run when page changed ? 
Here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="mGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UrunId">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddenTr" FooterStyle-CssClass="hiddenTr" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddenTr">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("UrunId") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="İsim">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("UrunAdi") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fiyat">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("UrunFiyati") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Para Birimi">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("ParaTipi") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kategori">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("UrunKategori") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sınıf">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%#Eval("MP") %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable({
            "language": {
                "search": "Ara",
                "lengthMenu": "Her sayfada _MENU_  kayıt göster.",
                "infoFiltered": "_MAX_ kayıt arasından filtrelendi.",
                "info": "_PAGES_ sayfa arasıdan _PAGE_.sayfa gösteriliyor.",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "İlk",
                    "last": "Son",
                    "next": "Sonraki",
                    "previous": "Önceki"
                }
            }
        });
        SatirlaraOnclickAt();
    });

        function SatirlaraOnclickAt() {
            $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr").click(function () {
                var ilkSatir = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>").find("tr:first").find("td:first").text();
                var secilenSatir = $(this).find("td:first").text();
                if (ilkSatir != secilenSatir) {
                    var id = $(this).find("td:first").text();
                    alert(id);
                }       
            });
        }
```

Like I said, functions work well but I need to run onclick function each time the page changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an attribut `fnDrawCallback`, like :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
      alert( 'DataTables has redrawn the table' );
    }
  } );
} );
```

This function is called on every 'draw' event, and allows you to dynamically modify any aspect you want about the created DOM.

Doc : http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks